# How to resize and change color of icon in a button?

Tags: android, android-button, android-icons

I am using **android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/share_icon"** in android button to show icon. I want to change color and size of icon. Below is my code

```
<Button
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="#66ccff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/share_icon"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="Send An Invite"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:tint="@color/white_color"
        />
```

Comment: what is your source icon? is it vector xml or jpg/png?

Comment: do you want to change it dynamically or you want to keep it static?

Comment: my source icon is in png format

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question little more. What you have tried till now to solve your issue. Please mention all these things in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Open the xml file of share_icon in mipmap and change colour and resize from there.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** The mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only. Any other drawable assets
>   you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before.

**Follow these steps:**

> **Step #1**
>
> > Wrap your resource in a drawable that defines your desired size similar to:
> >
> > ```
> >  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> >  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
> >
> >       <item
> >          android:drawable="@drawable/{your icon}"
> >          android:width="@dimen/icon_size"
> >          android:height="@dimen/icon_size" />
> >
> >  </layer-list >
> > ```
>
> **Step #2**
>
> > Remove the `android:drawableLeft` tag from your `Button`
>
> **Step #3**
>
> > Add this code to your `Activity` / `Fragment`
> >
> > ```
> > int tintColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context,
> > android.R.color.{your button color});
> >
> > Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.{your button id});
> >
> > Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.{drawable that you made earlier});
> >
> > drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
> > DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable.mutate(), tintColor);
> >
> > drawable.setBounds( 0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
> > drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
> >
> > button.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
> > ```

**Keep in mind:** (*Assuming you didn't know*)

- For the above code to work, you should add an `id` to your `Button`.
- If you're using an Activity, use `getApplicationContext()` and if you're using a Fragment, use `getContext()`
- Add the desired color to the `colors.xml` file